# Jumping to anchors in JSP

Tags: html, jsp, anchor

When jumping to anchors on a JSP, HTML anchors do not work.  Eg, something like

```
<a href="#name">Link</a>
...
<div id="name"></div>
```

fails because the server actually looks for a file named "filename.jps#name" and returns an error.  Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is called a [fragment identifier](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/intro.html#fragment-uri) and the target can be a named anchor or an identified element, for example

```
<a href="#foo">go to foo</a>
<a name="foo">foo</a>
<div id="foo">foo</div>
```

with the named anchor variation demonstrated in [**this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4tYMj/)

Please also note that the [HTML5 specification](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-a-element) has deprecated the `name` attribute for `a` elements has been dropped, so an `id` would be the only HTML5 valid way to [navigate to a fragment identifier](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#scroll-to-fragid).

Comment: *Must*? Wrong. An element ID is also perfectly valid. See http://jsfiddle.net/NTSjt/

Comment: Nice spot thanks @BalusC. I have updated my answer. I also remembered that anchor `name` is deprecated in HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you've set a `<base>` tag in your document. All identifier links are also relative to it. If this is true, then you need to change your identifier links from

```
<a href="#name">
```

to

```
<a href="${pageContext.request.requestURI}#name">
```

#### See also:

- [Is it recommended to use the <base> html tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889076/is-it-recommended-to-use-the-base-html-tag/1889957#1889957)